# When converting a Json to an Avro file only 3/4 of the lines are converted, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, json, hadoop, avro

This my code:

```
package hadoopPlayground;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.Decoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.Encoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class json2AVRO {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
    String filename = "ds214_arrivi_mensili.json";
    File JSONFile = new File(filename);
    String filename2 = "ds214_arrivi_mensili.avsc";
    File AVSCFile = new File(filename2);

    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(JSONFile));
    BufferedReader read2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(AVSCFile));

    String outputName = JSONFile.toString().substring(0, 
            JSONFile.toString().lastIndexOf(".")) + ".avro"; 

    String json = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(read);
    String schema = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(read2);

    InputStream input;
    Encoder encoder;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output;

            Schema schema1 = new Schema.Parser().parse(AVSCFile);

            DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema1);

            input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());

            output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);

            Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema1, din);

            System.out.println(decoder);

            encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(output, null);
            GenericRecord datum;

            GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer1 = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema1);

            File file= new File(outputName);

            DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> dataWriter = new DataFileWriter<GenericRecord>(writer1);


            dataWriter.create(schema1, file);
            try
            {
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                            datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
                            dataWriter.append(datum);

                            System.out.println(datum);

                            output.close();
                        }                   
            }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
            }
            finally
            {
                //Here is the flushing and closing
                try
                {
                    if (encoder != null)
                    {
                        encoder.flush();
                    }
                    if (output != null)
                    {
                        output.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            }
        }
```

The file is converted to AVRO correctly (apparently), but when I try to convert my AVRO to JSON from the terminal it only shows 1692 lines out of the 2016 expected... what's wrong?

I've already checked my JSON and converting my JSON to AVRO from the terminal I have no problem whatsoever. There are no strange symbols at line 1692 btw.

Comment: I don't think you want that `output.close()` inside your for-loop there (you already have it in the `finally` block). You may also need to `flush()` it in the `finally`.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I've already tried it, no way